# Discord.js Error with my embed and idk how to resolve it

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i have a embed on my ready.js that sends it to a channel, and its giving me this error

```html
ValidationError: Expected the value to be an object, but received string instead
    at ObjectValidator.handle (/root/ZyruzBot/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1161:25)
    at ObjectValidator.parse (/root/ZyruzBot/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:113:88)
    at EmbedBuilder.setAuthor (/root/ZyruzBot/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/messages/embed/Embed.cjs:42:37)
    at sendTicketMSG (/root/ZyruzBot/events/ready.js:13:10)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/root/ZyruzBot/events/ready.js:86:7)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
  validator: 's.object(T)',
  given: ' Cria um ticket aqui'
}
```

Heres the embed and the start of the code:

```js
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
  name: 'ready',
  async execute(client) {
    console.log('Bot Online!')
    console.log('Bot Dev Chain');
    const oniChan = client.channels.cache.get(client.config.ticketChannel)

    function sendTicketMSG() {
      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setColor('ff0000')
        .setAuthor('ðŸŽ« Cria um ticket aqui', client.user.avatarURL())
        .setDescription('Aqui pode abrir um ticket para obter\n\n **__<:SupportTeam:1013602711683473499>  Suporte\n <:Servers:1013601908105171014>  Adquirir a sua vps\n <a:developer_bot:1013602040745824336>  Adquirir o seu bot de discord\n <a:partnership:1013602912162828308>  Fazer uma Parceria__**')
        .setFooter(client.config.footerText, client.user.avatarURL())
      const row = new client.discord.MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(
          new client.discord.MessageButton()
          .setCustomId('open-ticket')
          .setLabel('Cria um ticket aqui')
          .setEmoji('ðŸŽ«')
          .setStyle('PRIMARY'),
        );

      oniChan.send({
        embeds: [embed],
        components: [row]
      })
    }
```

Idk whats generating this error, if you guys know please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Your error lies in the `.setAuthor()` Method. It seems, that you use a newer version of discord.js in which this method requests an Object with the information.

In this link is another example using an object, maybe this will resolve your issue.
[EmbedBuilder](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-the-embed-constructor)

Comment: I did do it like that, but didnt work